# Postgres (Amazon RDS) how to calculate weighted average

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4

I am using an Amazon RDS Postgres database (9.4.4), and I would like to calculate the weighted mean of some data.

I have found the following extension which looks perfect for the job. 
https://github.com/Kozea/weighted_mean

However I am now unsure of how to install the extension, as my initial research shows that only 'supported' extensions are allowed.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport

What options do i have for using this extension. I don't want to have to re-invent the wheel, and I am not familiar with installing any kind of function/extension within Postgres.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why you just don't issue a simple query like this:

```
select 
  case when sum(quantity) = 0 then 
   0 
  else 
   sum(unitprice * quantity) / sum(quantity) 
  end 
from sales;
```

of course you need to change your fields (unitprice, quantity)

Comment: indeed solution for RDS

Comment: You can avoid the `CASE` and the duplicate `SUM` by using `NULLIF` and `COALESCE`: `COALESCE(sum(unitprice * quantity) / NULLIF(sum(quantity) , 0), 0)`. I'm not sure this is *that* much better, but I'm not at all fond of `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 3):

The `SUM(value*weight)/SUM(weight)` answer is fine, but if you need to reuse it constantly it is more convenient to create an aggregate function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION avg_weighted_step(state numeric[], value numeric, weight numeric)
RETURNS numeric[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN array[state[1] + value*weight, state[2] + weight];
END;
$$ IMMUTABLE;


CREATE FUNCTION avg_weighted_finalizer(state numeric[])
RETURNS numeric
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF state[2] = 0 THEN
        RETURN null;
    END IF;
    RETURN state[1]/state[2];
END;
$$ IMMUTABLE;


CREATE AGGREGATE avg_weighted(value numeric, weight numeric) (
    sfunc = avg_weighted_step, 
    stype = numeric[],
    finalfunc = avg_weighted_finalizer,
    initcond = '{0,0}' );
```

Example Usage:

```
$ table tmp;
v  w 
-- -
 1 2
10 1
(2 rows)

$ select avg_weighted(v, w) from tmp;
   avg_weighted    
------------------
4.0000000000000000
(1 row)

$ select avg_weighted(v, w) from tmp where v is null;
avg_weighted 
------------
           ∅
(1 row)
```

Comment: Great! and AWS RDS compatible!, (my solution is almost identical to yours.  I used "sql" instead of "plpgsql").

Answer (score 2):

In order to register new custom extension you need to add appropriate scripts to `contrib` directory of Postgres installation. AWS **does NOT** allow you to have such a granular control.

Long story short, there is no way you can add any custom extensions (beside the ones specified in the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport) you provided or from [`pg_available_extensions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/view-pg-available-extensions.html) view) to Amazon RDS service.

This is one of the drawbacks of using DBaaS (database as a service) solutions.

Comment: Thanks, i am a huge fan on DBaaS but I guess there is no perfect solution.